# Disable the Ctrl-Alt-Delete event through Java program

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-events, jdesktoppane

I am creating a desktop application using the JDesktopPane. I'm almost complete, but when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>, it leaves my application. How can I prevent that action?

Comment: As I'm not certain, I won't offer an official answer, but I don't believe it is possible. On Windows, ctrl-alt-del is a reserved key combination.  It would be a security flaw to allow applications the ability to override it.

Answer (score 11):

Fact is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> never actually entering your application. Os traps <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> before it is send to your application. So you can't trap it.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> cannot be overridden. It is a security feature.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do that. The behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is enforced by the operating system, for good reasons: it makes sure that you can always bail-out of a faulty application.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/AntonioWinLock.aspx

lists several possibilities, from disabling the taskmanager to injecting keyboard hooks. But I doubt there's some built-in java functionality for that.