# Is there any way block Control-Alt-Delete in java?

Tags: java, key, controls, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to block the control key in java. I have looked and looked but I have not found any way to do it thanks in advance

Comment: [Disable the Ctrl-Alt-Delete event through Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616341/disable-the-ctrl-alt-delete-event-through-java-program) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to block CTRL+ALT+DELETE. In any way, shape or form. It is an absolute guarantee against hacking.